# Sum of two sine curves

Tags: trigonometry

How can we compute the sum 
$$
 \sin(f_1) + \sin(f_2)
$$
I know it is
$$
  2\sin\left(\frac{f_2 + f_1}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{f_2 - f_1}{2}\right)
$$
but how can it be derived with elementary trigonometric identites?

Answer (score 2):

The sine angle addition rule reads:

$$\sin(u\pm v)=\sin(u)\cos(v)\pm\sin(v)\cos(u)$$

You can prove your identity by rewriting $f_1=\frac{f_2+f_1}{2}-\frac{f_2-f_1}{2}$ and similarily for $f_2$ and applying the sine addition formula twice.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_1= \frac{f_1+f_2}{2}+\frac{f_1-f_2}{2}$$
$$f_2= \frac{f_1+f_2}{2}-\frac{f_1-f_2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(f_1) + \sin(f_2)=\sin \cfrac {2f_1}{2}+ \sin\cfrac {2f_2}{2}$$